# Migration to Hibernate 6 and loading of @ElementCollection

Tags: java, hibernate

During migration from Hibernate 5.6 to Hibernate 6.2 I faced an issue with lazy loading of an element collection which boils down to the following minimal example.

I have an entity

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class EntityWithPrimitiveCollection {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String x;

    @ElementCollection
    @OrderColumn
    private List<String> ys;
}
```

And a native query to search for this entity and load it joining `ys`:

```java
public EntityWithPrimitiveCollection findByX(String x) {
    var query = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class).createNativeQuery(
            """
            SELECT {e.*},
                y.entity_with_primitive_collection_id AS {y.key},
                y.ys_order AS {y.index},
                y.ys AS {y.element}
            FROM entity_with_primitive_collection AS e
            INNER JOIN entity_with_primitive_collection_ys AS y 
                ON e.id = y.entity_with_primitive_collection_id
            WHERE e.x = :x
            """)
            .setParameter("x", x);

    query.addRoot("e", EntityWithPrimitiveCollection.class);
    query.addJoin("y", "e.ys");
    return (EntityWithPrimitiveCollection) query.getSingleResult();
}
```

This query is a minimal example, the actual is more complex and I do not see how rewrite it in HQL (and use fetch graphs).

In Hibernate 5 this query works fine loads the entity and collection `ys` without additional queries (checked via `spring.jpa.show-sql=true`). In Hibernate 6 it sets `ys` to a lazy loading proxy (a `LazyInitializationException` is observed later).

The questions:

1. Is this approach valid for Hibernate 5 or it works by a mistake?
2. What is the proper approach in Hibernate 6 to load such entities when using native queries?